# Is it possible to add a CSS link within HTML tags?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 CSS and I placed my 1st CSS on

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

I want to put my 2nd CSS on a specific html tag because it affects my 1st CSS if i put it also in the `head` tag. Can I do that? like... this is what I'm planning to do. is it correct?

```
<div link="type:text/css; href:???"> </div>
```

Comment: no its not correct, you cant add link in such tags

Comment: How does the 2nd one affect the 1st one? Can you put some code?

Comment: i add a hover . on my first css the color of my hover or if it is active is color blue , the second css is color grey,. when i put the 1st and 2nd css link on the head tag, the hover of the 2nd tag is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do; but, if you want to specify a specific tag to give it different properties you can use CSS classes to do that.

HTML

```
<div class="two"></div>
```

CSS

```
div.two{
    /* style here */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong.

There's no such thing as a link attribute that you could put on a specific element/tag. Only a `<link>` tag is available.

If your 2nd CSS affects/overrides your first CSS, then you might have styled an element on the 1st CSS and styled it again on the 2nd CSS. For example:

CSS 1

---

```
div{
    background-color: red;
}
```

CSS 2

---

```
div{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

You'll notice that the `<div>` will have a blue background color. This is because CSS 2 has overridden your style on CSS 1. If you don't want to override some styles, make use of classes or ids. Create a unique class name or id for your HTML elements/tags.

Answer (score 1):

No! You can't do that. But you can [override the css](https://www.google.com.np/search?q=override+the+css&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=dO5IUv7hJZDrrAeuroHwDg) if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it like this:

```
<head>

    <link type="text/css" href="name1.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link type="text/css" href="name.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```